# How to apply conditional routing in Angular where the condition is to make sure that the previous page has been visited?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have an Angular web app where to sign up you go through different pages:

1. Fill in your name and email
2. Fill in your password
3. Fill in your confirmation code

Hence the URL changes from `website.com/intake` to `website.com/intake/signup` to `website.com/intake/confirmation`.

My problem is that it is currently possible for a user to change the url from `website.com/intake` to `website.com/intake/signup` and finish the registration without filling the other information. I would like to prevent that but I am not sure how to use routing in this case.

I want to make sure that the user can go to the next page only if he has been to the first one and has filled in. Now I know, if I make the form fields  `* required` it will not allow the user to go further but he will still be able to bypass that by changing the URL.

How do I solve that?

Comment: In your app.component.ts you could force a navigate to /intake. Whenever the app loads the user would be force back to the /intake even if they try to manually navigate.
Otherwise you would need state management that would persist between reloads, and then have startup logic in place that forces the user to the correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use guards. Create a conditional to restrict the route you wish.

If the user hasn't filled the form, redirect him to the form.

[Angular guards tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-route-guards/#:%7E:text=The%20Angular%20supports%20several%20guards%20like%20CanActivate%2C%20CanDeactivate%2C,Guards%20by%20building%20an%20example%20angular%20guards%20application.)